# Unable to Run Unit Tests of Custom Flutter Package

Tags: flutter, android-studio, unit-testing

I am new to Flutter and learning it to my own. For learning purposes I have created a small custom Flutter package with some value returning methods. I have written unit test that I want to run and test them, but the whenever I ran the tests the Android Studio is saying "Test framework quite unexpectedly"

[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/othlM.png)

I just want to know is it possible to run the tests for custom Flutter Package, or is that something I am missing or doing wrong!

Thanks in advance

I have tried setting/editing the run configurations as well:

[Edit Configurations Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkUYD.png)

Comment: Follow the given instructions from the error. The easiest way to do that is to create another flutter project and paste the dart/flutter files there so it will create a new android and ios folder for you.

Comment: How do you write the code ? share some code snippet .

Comment: See [Upgrading pre 1.12 Android projects](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects)

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code :-

```
class FileExtensionUtil {
  static String extractExtension(String filePath) {
    List<String> parts = filePath.split('.');
  
    if (parts.length > 1) {
      return parts.last;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

Create a test.dart file in test package  and Write this code for test .

```
void main() {
  test('Extract file extension', () {
    String filePath = '/data/user/0/com.app.give_a_day/cache/file_picker/2808202312281000_099473.pdf';
    String extension = FileExtensionUtil.extractExtension(filePath);
    
    expect(extension, 'pdf');
  });

  test('No valid file extension', () {
    String filePath = 'no_extension_file';
    String extension = FileExtensionUtil.extractExtension(filePath);

    expect(extension, '');
  });
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same but see the screen shots I am facing error on running my tests!

Comment: @HappyCoder I see your error . Upgrade your flutte sdk as well as pub dependencies versions